# Программное создание .cs файла

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть Windows Forms приложение, там есть разный функционал и одна из функций - запуск написанного кода. Для этого есть несколько кнопок: открыть, выбрать, создать. При нажатии на кнопку создать, появляется выбор местоположения файла и его дальнейшего начального заполнения.
После открытия этого файла, я не могу использовать свои пространства имён, а также те, для которых нужно указывать ссылки, к примеру System.Drawing, точнее, Visual Studio просто не даёт мне подсказки с ними и их классами, методами. Как это можно реализовать? И можно ли вообще с одним .cs файлом или нужно дополнительно создавать .sln и другие файлы?

Comment: cs файл - это файл с исходным кодом. sln файл - это инструкции, как собирать ваш проект. Для компиляции одного файла вам не надо sln. Для поддержки автокомплита и компиляции на лету используйте Roslyn и Compiler Services

Comment: Как я понимаю, то Roslyn мне поможет, если я захочу в своей программе писать код. Но там только создаётся .cs файл, а его я уже запускаю в Visual Studio.

Comment: Так можно ли заставить нормально работать IntelliSense в одном .cs файле? Как сделать так, чтобы IntelliSense мог давать подсказки на посторонние пространства имён?